# Using Time to live with Camel framework in Java

Tags: java, apache-camel, integration, activemq-classic

I am using doing integration work with Camel and using the HTTP endpoint as a proxy to route certain messages to an HTTP endpoint.  I have my route configured to use my custom error handler which places failed messages in a queue that I specified (Dead Letter Channel pattern).

```
<route>
    ...
    <to uri="direct:MessageTypeGuaranteed"/>
</route>

<route errorHandlerRef="MyCustomErrorHandler">
    <from uri="direct:MessageTypeGuaranteed">
    <to uri="http://dummyUri?throwExceptionOnFailure=true"/>
</route>
```

When anything fails to get delivered to my http endpoint, it's being added to my custom queue ("CustomFailedMessageQueue"), and I have a separate route that attempts to retry these messages:

```
<route>
    <from uri="jms:queue:CustomFailedMessageQueue">
    <to uri="direct:MessageTypeGuaranteed"/>
</route>
```

What I'd like to do is to be able to specify that I only want a message to live say for 10 seconds.  So I am trying to set time to live on my http destination itself.

For example, I have a processor that does something like this:

```
exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, "http://localhost/nodeserver?timeToLive=10000");
```

However, I think I have misunderstood the documentation.  The timeToLive option is only valid when passing it to the jms component, correct?  In other words, if I want to make use of time to live with this end point, I will need to do that handling myself in a processor, correct?

Comment: just to get clear, message to live for 10 secs in queue right ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: so i think you should write this on your jms ! Can you show your DeadLetterChannel configuration in route ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes TimeToLive is an option from the JMS spec that the Camel JMS components support. That options has no meaning for other components such as HTTP.

It seems like you may want to use a filter EIP and discard the message if its *to old*, and you can use a java method etc to implement some code that figures out if its to old or not, and return a boolean

```
public boolean isNotToOld(Exchange exchange) {
   ...
   return true // to accept and process the message
}
```

See more about the filter eip here

- http://camel.apache.org/message-filter

And you can use it in a route something a like

```
  <from uri="direct:MessageTypeGuaranteed">
  <filter>
    <method ref="myBean" method="isNotToOld"/>
    <to uri="http://dummyUri?throwExceptionOnFailure=true"/>
  </filter>
```

Comment: Claus, you sir are a gentleman and a scholar.  I really appreciate your engagement in this community.  Also, your book is awesome!